# Purpose of Indian man concerning little boy in Lion

Tags: plot-explanation, lion

I wonder what was the intent of the suspicious man from 2016 movie *Lion* who met little Sheru at the lady's apartment, fluently estimated his physical qualities and wanted to take the boy with him.

Answer (score 13):

That man has plans to take that boy and force him into either labor or prostitution or sell his organs. These would be the reasons why he was fluently estimating his physical qualities.

That man was in Child Trafficking business. That's illegal and usually happens to poor people who don't have enough money to have food for at least one time a day. For more information, you can look at [Child Trafficking in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_trafficking_in_India). Sometimes, they don't even pay those people and forcefully abduct children.

Comment: Meaningful response.